# Hash md5: Pyspark shell and spark-submit don't give the same output on timestamp column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hash

With PySpark, I used md5 function to hash some colums of a dataframe.
The dataframe is a read from a hive table. I have casted all the columns into string type and make sure that the values are correct before running the md5 hash.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import md5
df_hive = spark.sql("select * from db.table1 where day=1")
df_hive  = df_hive.select([sqlf.col(c).cast("string") for c in df_hive.columns])
dfha = df_hive.withColumn("hash_col",md5("timestamp_col"))
dfha.write.format("csv").save("path")
```

The hash gives the same results in pyspark shell as in Databricks but different values on timestamp column when I run the process through spark-submit.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you show what is the difference, and what versions of the pyspark & DB are used

Comment: The difference is only in the hash values. The issue was that I had configure my sparkSession variable to use a different timezone on Databricks/Pyspark vs spark-submit.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input, the hash, and the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my sparkSession variable used a different timezone on Databricks from the one the spark-submit environment.
Forcing the timezone in the spark session variable in the script solved the issue.

```
spark = (pyspark
     .sql
     .SparkSession
     .builder
     .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Your Timezone")
     .getOrCreate()
    )
```

Or after creating your spark session variable you can use the method mentioned by @Luca

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old. I just had a similar (problem notebook executed by hand vs in a pipeline) and in one the timezone is set and in the other the default value. Hence the hint of Bentech in the comments is probably correct.

For me synchronising the timezones with help of `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Your Timezone")` fixed the problem.

Comment: The difference is only in the hash values. The issue was that I had configure my sparkSession variable to use a different timezone on Databricks/Pyspark vs spark-submit.

Comment: Hi @Bentech am I right in guessing that you solved your hashing issue? Is Luca's answer a viable solution? If it is close I would suggest providing an edit to this answer to improve it, or provide [your own answer to your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) which would make for great documentation for others in the future facing the same problem.